# Typescript error: type this is not assignable to type this

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript and I am working on one project and I am trying to set up the project and I got an error from backend typescript I don't know how I solve it if someone knows that help me.

**TS File**

```
import { Document, Model, model, Schema } from "mongoose";
import { IUser } from "./GenUser";

/**
* Interface to model GenStatus for TypeScript.
* @param cStatusCode: string 
* @param cStatusName: string 
* @param cStatusDesc: string
* @param iEnteredby: string
* @param tEntered: Date
* @param iUpdatedby: string
* @param tUpdated: Date;
*/
export interface IStatus extends Document {
  cStatusCode: string;
  cStatusName: string;
  cStatusDesc: string;
  iEnteredby: IUser['_id'];
  tEntered: Date;
  iUpdatedby: IUser['_id'];
  tUpdated: Date;
}

const GenStatus: Schema = new Schema({
  cStatusCode: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  cStatusName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  cStatusDesc: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  iEnteredby: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  tEntered: {
    type: Date
  },
  iUpdatedby: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  tUpdated: {
    type: Date
  }
});

const Status: Model<IStatus> = model("gen_Status", GenStatus);

export default Status;
```

**Error**

> src/models/GenStatus.ts:55:7 - error TS2322: Type 'Model<Document<any, any, any>, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Model<IStatus, {}, {}>'.
> The types returned by 'create(...)' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'Promise<Document<any, any, any>[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IStatus[]>'.
> Type 'Document<any, any, any>[]' is not assignable to type 'IStatus[]'.
> Type 'Document<any, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'IStatus'.
> 55 const Status: Model = model("gen_Status", GenStatus);

Comment: no error in ts playground https://tsplay.dev/WK7ygW

Comment: @captain-yossarian Hello sir but i got error on this.

Comment: @captain-yossarian if i do `Model<IStatus>` to `any` it's resolve but that is not good if you have another solution please give that.

Comment: please provide an example

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mLLqbm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve it and the answer is here.

**Before**

`const Status: Model<IStatus> = model("gen_Status", GenStatus);`

**After**

`const Status: Model<IStatus> = model<IStatus>("gen_Status", GenStatus);`